# Conditional data input validation in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hZ7FaWq2tGfdxCK2VI8xNb2v_R1bDftmvbuPURUUeRY/edit?usp=sharing) that contains three pages:

```
Projects
```

[image]

```
Tasks
```

[image]

`Tasks` are related to `Projects`

```
Calendar
```

[image]

Related to `Projects` and `Tasks`.

When I select `Project` in `Calendar` and go to `Task` drop down I have all tasks there. How to make dropdown that contains only `Tasks` related to selected in column `B` `Project`?

Answer (score 0):

A drawback to using *project* and *task* drop-downs in *the calendar* sheet is that maintaining valid input is tricky. For example, if you select a matching project/task pair and then change the project, the task is technically invalid. What should happen in that case? Note, this is not a problem specific to Google Sheets, but rather a general computer programming problem.

A simpler and error-free approach is to combine the two drop-downs into one so that only valid project/task pairs can be selected. *And*, it so happens to be easier to implement than synchronized drop-downs anyway!

To do this:

1. Add a new column to the *tasks* sheet which concatenates the project and task columns. Here's an example formula: `=concat(A1, concat(": ", B1))`. The output looks like this: *Project A: Job 1 for project A*.
2. Use the new column in the *tasks* sheet as the data-validation criteria for you *task* column in the *calendar* sheet.
3. Delete the *project* column from the *calendar* sheet.

So what you end up with in the *calendar* sheet is a *task* column with entries like this:

- Project A: Job 1 for project A
- Project A: Job 2 for project A
- Project B: Job 1 for project B

Hence, it's impossible to mismatch the project and task.